# Haxe Run System Commands as an adminstrator

Tags: haxe

As I am very new to haxe.

The following is my program in haxe where I am trying to retrieve the list of files opened in windows client. Openfiles is the command which gives the list of files opened in windows machine , which needs to be executed as an administrator. I am failing to execute the program which is giving no output.

```
class Hello {
public static function main() {
    trace("Hello World!");
    if(Sys.systemName()=="Windows"){
    //var x = Sys.command("Openfiles",[]);
    var output = new sys.io.Process("ipconfig", []).stdout.readAll().toString();
    trace("output:::"+output);
    }

    if(Sys.systemName()=="Linux"){
    //var x = Sys.command("Openfiles",[]);
    var output = new sys.io.Process("ifconfig", []).stdout.readAll().toString();
    trace("output:::"+output);
    }

 }
}
```

How to execute Openfiles system command as an administrator ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

for Linux you can do this:

```
var output = new Process("bash", ["-c 'echo rootS_PASswoRd | sudo -S ifconfig'"]).stdout.readAll().toString();
    trace("output:::"+output);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: *Do NOT run this in a loop*, you will be left with 'defunct' processes, which if you leave it running in a loop will leave your system unusable until you end your Haxe process.

Make sure to call the process.exitCode() and process.close()